# Validate ASP.NET Dropdownlist Control with bootstrap Validator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a asp dropdownlist `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddIndProvince" data-style="btn-default" CssClass="form-control input" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddIndProvince_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="8"></asp:DropDownList>` On Page load event I inserted "--Select--" item at index 0.
Now I am facing problem while I am validating it with bootstrap validator. Its returning valid for "--Select--" item. like below image. 
[image]

How I can validate this.Below us my current script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {          
             $('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
                container: '#messages',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {                   
                    <%=ddIndProvince.UniqueID%>:{
                        validators:{
                            notEmpty:{
                                messages:'please select province'
                            }
                        }
                    }                              
                }   
            });
        });         
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrapValidator is validating the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag in your html markup.

Your javascript code is correct. What you need to do is make sure, the value attribute is empty:

Change your markup from:

```
<option value="Something is in here">--Select--</option>
```

To:

```
<option value="">--Select--</option>
```

Do this in your Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*...*/

    //Insert new Item at Index 0 with text "--Select--" and no value
    ddIndProvince.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", String.Empty));
    ddIndProvince.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```